# How to call stored procedure without error in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I  call a stored procedure without error in ADO.NET Entity Framework? If I use the code below, I get an error:

```
adminNameContext.AddItemCategory(12, "ggf", DateTime.Now);
```

**Error:**

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'NetTanitimTestModel.Categories'. A member of the type, 'ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_AddItemCategory]  
(  
  @item int,   
  @category nvarchar(50),  
  @date smalldatetime   
)  
as  
begin  
  if(@item=-1)  
  begin  
    insert into Categories(PARENTID,Category,Date) values(null,@category,@date)  
  end  
  else  
  begin  
    insert into Categories(PARENTID,Category,Date) values(@item,@category,@date)  
  end  
end
```

i have Categories table which has got 3 columns: PARENTID,Category,Date

Comment: The error says it all: you are trying to reference a column in the resultset ('ID') which isn't there...

Comment: Shows us what the stored procedure looks like (T-SQL code), and show us what table (the table structure) it runs against

Comment: marc_s;  i refreshed my question. Please look again :)

Comment: I would *STRONGLY* recommend *NOT* calling your stored procs something with "sp_" at the beginning; that prefix is reserved for Microsoft use *ONLY*. I don't think this is the problem here, but just as a best practice - NEVER call your stored procs sp_(something) - use proc_(something) or whatever else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if your EF data model and your database are not in sync anymore. It seems as if your "Categories" object in the EF data model has an "ID" field but the table does not.

I would update the EF data model from the database and see if that fixes the problem. To do this, open up the EDMX designer and right click on an empty spot in the design surface, and pick the "Update model from database" option. That should bring the two worlds back into sync.

Marc

Comment: What fields are on your "Categories" object in the EF data model?

Answer (score 0):

Mitch Wheat gave you the answer. You're trying to use the ID column, but the table has a PARENTID column.